# How To avoid image flickering when change the image source dynamically in WP7...?

Tags: windows-phone-7

in My project i change the image source during my media element playing, after end media element i restore the previous image. During the image source change the image will flickering.How will avoid the flickering effect during the image source change dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to do that:

1. Create your ImageSource separately, wait until it has finished loading, and only then assign it to your image control.

   For instance, if you're using a `BitmapSource`, subscribe to the `DownloadCompleted` event, and use that event to assign the `BitmapSource` to your Image control.
2. Simulate double buffering: create a second Image control, put it in background, and when it has finished loading remove the foreground Image control.